# Creating a BigQuery Transfer Service with more complex reges

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a bucket that stores files based on a transaction time into a filename structure like

```
gs://my-bucket/YYYY/MM/DD/[autogeneratedID].parquet
```

Lets assume this structure dates back to `2015/01/01`

Some of the files might arrive late, so in theory a new file could be written to the `2020/07/27` structure tomorrow.

I now want to create a BigQuery table that inserts all files with transaction date `2019-07-01` and newer.

My current strategy is to slice the past into small enough chunks to just run batch loads, e.g. by month. Then I want to create a transfer service that listens for all new files coming in.
I cannot just point it to `gs://my-bucket/*` as this would try to load the date prior to `2019-07-01`.

So basically I was thinking about encoding the "future looking file name structures" into a suitable regex, but it seems like the wildcard names https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames only allow for very limited syntax which is not as flexible as awk regex for instance.

I know there are streaming inserts into BQ but still hoping to avoid that extra complexity and just make a smart configuration of the transfer config following the batch load.

Comment: I cannot follow. There are certainly many ways, e.g. materialized views, automatic date-based partitions, and sure, streaming data.

Comment: Reading the docs, they only offer recursive `**` wildcards. That is, it looks like you need to do multiple requests, such as: `gs://my-bucket/2019/07/**`, `gs://my-bucket/2019/08/**`, `gs://my-bucket/2019/09/**`, `gs://my-bucket/2019/1**`, `gs://my-bucket/2020/**`.

Comment: Thanks Peter! This will probably be the easiest workaround if we want to avoid streaming inserts, even though I somehow dislike the idea as it looks a bit duct-taped. But fair enough, these configs can still be auto-generated with some simple bash magic, so at least it would be repeatable / paramterized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) with [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage). When you query your external table, you can use the pseudo column `_FILE_NAME` in the where condition of your request and filter on this.